# Which ASP.NET commands can lead to insecure code?

Tags: asp.net, sql, security

Personally, I try and write secure ASP.NET code. However, I have become quite paranoid about the code I write, as I used to work for a Registrar (high fraud targets). Are there any ASP.NET functions I should look at with extreme scrutiny (other than SQL access - I know enough not to do dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent MSDN article: [Security Practices: ASP.NET 2.0 Security Practices at a Glance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx).

Excerpt:

> **How to prevent cross site scripting**
>
> Validate input and encode output.
>   Constrain input by validating it for
>   type, length, format, and range. Use
>   the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method to
>   encode output if it contains input
>   from the user, such as input from form
>   fields, query strings, and cookies or
>   from other sources, such as databases.
>   Never just echo input back to the user
>   without validating and/or encoding the
>   data. The following example shows how
>   to encode a form field.
>
> ```
> Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["name"]));
> ```
>
> If you return URL strings that contain
>   input to the client, use the
>   HttpUtility.UrlEncode method to encode
>   these URL strings, as shown here.
>
> ```
> Response.Write(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(urlString));
> ```
>
> If you have pages that need to accept
>   a range of HTML elements, such as
>   through some kind of rich text input
>   field, you must disable ASP.NET
>   request validation for the page.
>
> **Turn On Custom Errors To Keep Errors Private**
>
> ```
> <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="YourErrorPage.htm" />
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mitch! I appreciate your response, however... the response you have given leads me to believe that this is a countermeasure for either unescaped SQL or for non-DB driven code. Reason being that it's all user-input storage based.

Also, URLEncoding things tends to "over-encode" in my experience, because it has to subscribe to URL encoding rules (very strict).

Also, with ASP.NET I try to avoid any Response.Writes. I find the ASP.NET code-infront controls give much better structural awareness to my HTML.

I'll give you +1 though, because you are still technically valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Never trust user input. Never assume client-side validation will prevent bad input data. Always ensure that ValidateRequest="true" and EnableEventValidation="true" in your web.config :

See [Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/) and [ASP.NET Security Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/).